# INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE after the installation of the AMD raid driver on a new Windows 10 installation

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, raid, amd-ryzen

I've a reinstalled Windows 10 on the same m2 drive where it was before (non-raid), with the same 2xSATA drives setup in RAID-1 used only for data storage.

After, I've installed the AMD RAIDXpert drivers and Windows fails to boot with the INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE error.

The chipset is an AMD X470 and the AMD RAID driver version is 9.3.0.266 (latest).

This setup was working with the previous Windows 10 installation.

The RAID array is marked as "online" and working in the BIOS.

The [AMD RAIDXpert documentation](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/53987_1.pdf) explains how to install the driver only during the Windows installation, it's not possible to install it after? Is there a way to just mount them on a a live OS and access the contained files?

Comment: The instructions assume you will be installing Windows on the RAID that is created.  Unless you changed to RAID mode (which wouldn't be proper unless the Windows installation itself was on the RAID) simply installing RAID drivers shouldn't have cause the problem you described.  What you actually want is likely `AMD RAIDXpert2 Management Application` which will allow you to configure 2 additional disks as a RAID.

Comment: `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE` error usually occurs when the BCD store becomes corrupted or is no longer pointing to the correct `\\<harddisk>\<volume>`. Boot to WinRE and run: **BIOS:** `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD` || **UEFI:** `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD`

Comment: Before installing the drivers, I assume the RAID volume is inaccessible? After you install the drivers it is. It’s probable the RAID volume has an existing boot volume on it, and Windows is trying to boot from it. Or, the RAID volume being visible has reordered the volumes as Windows sees them, so it is trying to boot the RAID volume. Disconnecting the RAID disks should solve the issue? The RAID volume should be connected and drivers installed during Windows installation - that is the simplest way to make sure Windows does not reorder the drives afterwards. But, it can be fixed, if you must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simple to solve: after the W10 installation I waited for Windows ending the automatic drivers download for the system. Then I launched the RAIDXpert installer and the drive became available.

It's a little bit crazy that the documentation isn't explicit about a simple use case like this, and talks only a lot about the raid installation during the SO installation. If I have a choice between a "software suite" and a driver, I choose always the driver, but this time I was wrong :.

Thank you @Ramhound for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue this week on a new MB. Same setup as the original question windows on a NVMe drive, 2 mirrored 4tb SATA drives for storage. Installed windows on the NVMe drive. After windows was setup I installed AMD raid drivers which is required to get the SATA drives working. As soon as the system is rebooted I would get the inaccessable boot device error. What causes the issue is the NVMe is part of the raid and when the AMD RAID driver is installed it replaces the Microsoft: windows Standard NVM express controller driver with a AMD AM4 raid driver and renames it to AMD Raid - bottom device. (It also adds a second AMD raid - bottom device) The fix is to install the raid driver driver and then immediately roll back the one that was changed from MS to AMD to the Microsoft driver before rebooting. This same issue was happening out of the blue on working systems in the past after doing windows updates when MS was pushing out the AMD driver in its auto updates. They have since pulled it from the windows updates.

Answer (score 0):

I've just hit this again and my solution was to ensure that NVME raid was enabled in the BIOS, even though I only wanted to raid SATA devices.

This was confusingly under the SATA section of my BIOS.

Once that was done, with the AMD raid driver, I could boot into windows without issue.